# Unable to update multiple records with one single query (CASE/WHEN))

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-update, case

I am trying to update multiple records for few columns in a table in SQL with following query.

(I wish to update A with A1, B with B1, C with C1 and on..)

```
UPDATE Employee 
SET CASE WHEN name ='A' then  'A1' END 
    CASE WHEN name ='B' then  'A2' END 
    CASE WHEN name ='C' then  'A3' END
    CASE WHEN name ='D' then  'A4' END 
    CASE WHEN name ='E' then  'A5' END 
    CASE WHEN name ='F' then  'A6' END 
    CASE WHEN name ='G' then  'A7' END 
    CASE WHEN name ='H' then  'A8' END 
    CASE WHEN name ='J' then  'A9' END 
    CASE WHEN name ='K' then  'B0' END 
    CASE WHEN name ='L' then  'B1' END ,
    CASE WHEN Category = 'recrods' THEN 'records' END ,
    CASE WHEN featureID ='140' then 'CV5' END
    WHERE School = '5000'
```

Getting error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'. Sure I am missing something here.

Please help me. Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a column as the first thing after the `set`.  Perhaps:

```
UPDATE Employee 
    SET name = (CASE WHEN name ='A' then  'A1' 
                     WHEN name ='B' then  'A2' 
                     WHEN name ='C' then  'A3'
                     WHEN name ='D' then  'A4' 
                     WHEN name ='E' then  'A5' 
                     WHEN name ='F' then  'A6' 
                     WHEN name ='G' then  'A7' 
                     WHEN name ='H' then  'A8' 
                     WHEN name ='J' then  'A9' 
                     WHEN name ='K' then  'B0' 
                     WHEN name ='L' then  'B1'
                     ELSE name
                 END),
        category = (CASE WHEN Category = 'recrods' THEN 'records' ELSE category END),
        featureID = (CASE WHEN featureID ='140' then 'CV5' else featureID END)
    WHERE School = '5000' ;
```

Comment: Worked as charm!! You are a life saver. Thanks :)